# How does adding 'use client' on top of a page effect my page SEO on NEXT.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js 13 app router and I'm wondering does using 'use client' on top of a page prevent crawlers to crawl my page? Is there any negative effects on adding 'use client' to my page regarding SEO?
Is there any tools to measure page SEO when developing?